# create a thumbnail for the video in vimeo by selecting frame

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3, vimeo-api

I need to create thumbnails for the video in `vimeo` in php (cakephp),

Please have a look at [this](http://vimeo.com/blog/post:514)

User will be selecting the particular frame by clicking on the Use this frame button.

Did anyone work on this, if so please help me..

Comment: If is not described in the APIs it can't be done outside Vimeo's upload system.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported in Vimeo's API. You will have to change it on vimeo.com.

The feature will be supported in the future though, so keep an eye on the [developer blog](http://vimeoapi.tumblr.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is now suppported in Vimeo's Api. Please take a look [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#/%7Bvideo_id%7D/pictures). You just need to set the `time` and `active` parameters in the following request.

> POST  `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/pictures`